# Perform search & replace using a callback command

Tags: vim

I'm trying to search & replace inside my file for all occurrences of a particular pattern, then call `toupper()` on each match. In practice, there aren't that many occurrences that I couldn't just do this by hand, but I'm curious to improve my Vim skills and find a (simple) way to get Vim to do this for me. I say simple, otherwise I'll just forget.

From a read over the Vim help for `s/`, I should be able to do something like this:

```
:%s/\vfunction ([a-z0-9_]+)/\="function " . toupper("\1")/g
```

(Assuming I'm uppercasing all function definition names).

This actually just replaces the function names with the control character `^A` though. How do I refer to the capturing group in the regexp?

Answer (score 4):

Apologies. I should read more closely. I'll answer my own question anyway, instead of deleting it. You need to use `submatch(n)` to refer to the capturing group:

```
:%s/\vfunction ([a-z0-9_]+)/\="function " . toupper(submatch(1))/g
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\U` in the replacement pattern.

```
:%s/\vfunction ([a-z0-9_]+)/function \U\1/
```

Comment: That's a useful trick, thanks! I was more curious about the general way to handle a callback routine, but for the uppercase example this is much easier :)

Comment: Second that. I too would love to know how to do it with a function.